# Refresh same view controller with new data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a song page with recommended songs in a table view. When a user clicks on a recommended song, I want to essentially reload the song page with the new data. To do that, I'm using this method, with a segue from the cell to its own view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let newSong = recommendedTitles[indexPath.row]

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("refreshSong", sender: newSong)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if segue.identifier == "refreshSong" {
            let newSong:String = sender as! String
            let song = segue.destinationViewController as! SongViewController
            song.search = newSong

        }
    }
```

But I'm getting an error at `let newSong:String = sender as! String`, that it `could not cast value of type recommendationCell to NSString`. Is the best way to do all of this with the aforementioned tableView methods?

Comment: what you want to pass in `newSong` ?

Comment: @DhavalThanki recommendedTitles[indexPath.row]

Comment: What kind of segue do you have in the storyboard? Seems that you already have the segue linked to the Cell

Comment: let newSong:String = recommendedTitles[indexPath.row] as?String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to declare global variable.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("refreshSong", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "refreshSong" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let song = segue.destinationViewController as! SongViewController
        song.search = recommendedTitles[(indexPath?.row)!]

    }
}
```

Comment: When I'm passing recommendedTitles[indexPath.row], I'm passing it to a string that is already being declared in viewDidLoad. How can I make sure that what I'm passing overrides what I'm setting in viewDidLoad?

Comment: you can declare `search` variable with default value in `SongViewController` `var search:String = ""` do not override value in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: So how would I make sure the recommendedTitles[indexPath.row] as the search variable overrides what I'm manually setting it as in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

you try this. Take the variable newSong in declaration section

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        newSong = recommendedTitles[indexPath.row]

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("refreshSong", sender: nil)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "refreshSong" {
            let song = segue.destinationViewController as! SongViewController
            song.search = newSong

        }
    }
```